# Selecting data from Excel based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with data such as date, time, and some other numbers.

What I want to do is create a macro that goes and selects all the data that falls in a certain time range.

For example, I will have a variable `start_time = 8 AM` and `end_time = 10 AM`.

So, I need to select all the columns that fall in that time range.

Comment: Sub getStartEndTime()
Dim ts300start As Variant 
Dim ts300end As Variant 
Range("B5").Activate 
ts300start = Range("B5").Value2 
ts300end = Range("B6").Value 
End Sub

SO what I'm trying here is I have the start time in cell B5 and End time in B6. I want to assign it to some variable (ts300) and then I have another sheet with data from specific time range. I want to find the data between the start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

```
   strdate = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a Date to Locate on This Worksheet", _
            Title:="DATE FIND", Default:=Format(Date, "Short Date"), Type:=1)
   If strdate = "False" Then Exit Sub
       strdate = Format(strdate, "Short Date")
       On Error Resume Next
           Set rCell = Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strdate), After:=Range("A1"),           LookIn:=xlFormulas _
               , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,               MatchCase:=False)

On Error GoTo 0
```

Similarly get the next range for the second date and set the range to a variable and RANGE.SELECT